# How to run c++ debugger for msvc on VS Code outside the Developer Command Prompt?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to configure my project on vscode rather than visual studio. And I want to use MSVC as compiler rather than MinGW. I have configure like the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc). But I find that there is no documentation refered to how to run c++ debugger for msvc on VS Code outside the Developer Command Prompt? So I ask this question over here.

Comment: The developer command prompt is just `%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"` (look at the shortcut in the [start] menu and open-file-location).  It's just a `cmd` prompt where `VsDevCmd.bat` has been run to setup the paths.  Examine the batch file for the details for your system.

Comment: Emm,because they are too small. The VS is perfect for a middle size and bigger project.(Yes, it's very awesome!) I think vscode is more convienent for these toy projects.@PaulSanders

Comment: Not really.  For toy stuff I compile from the command line.  Once that becomes a bore I use VS.  in either case, I fail to see what VS Code brings to the party.  The only reason I can see to avoid VS proper would be if your machine has inadequate resources to run it or if your broadband can't cope with the download.  Try it, you won't regret it.

Comment: Any chance you found a way to do this? I've tried a few times over the last two years and have yet to come up with a solution other than to generate solution files and do it from VS.